# Change behavior of stacked filters to or in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'd like something like the following:

```
q = db.session.query(db.models.Something).filter(a==a).filter(b==b).or().filter(c==c).filter(foo==bar)
```

This would mean a=a and b=b or c=c and d=d.

I would strongly preffer to avoid applying this within the filter calls themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use the [`or_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_) and [`and_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) functions:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_, and_

q = db.session.query(db.models.Something).filter(
    or_(
        and_(a==a, b==b),
        and_(c==c, foo==bar)
    ))
```

or you can use `&` and `|` operators:

```
q = db.session.query(db.models.Something).filter(
    (a==a) & (b==b) | (c==c) & (foo==bar))
```

See [Conjunctions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html#conjunctions) and [Common Filter Operations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators).

Comment: From the question: "I would strongly prefer to avoid applying this within the filter calls themselves."

Comment: @astex: These are the options, I am afraid.